# Can't Download Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.pdb

Tags: c#, pdb-files

I'm trying to debug into the source of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll referenced by my project, I also cofigurated the symbol server "http://referencesource.microsoft.com/symbols", "http://srv.symbolsource.org/pdb/Public" and "http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols", but still can't let VS to automaticlly download Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.*.dll pdb files, it seems the pdb files for these dll are not in the symbol servers.
Where can I get the pdb files for the version 1.0.0?

Thansk